Как загрузить в переменную типа Image картинку из каталога? C++/CLI
Я хотел бы в container загрузить картинку из каталога. Как это сделать?
sf::Image container;
System::Void Project1::MyForm::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    OpenFileDialog^ open_dialog = gcnew OpenFileDialog; //создание диалогового окна для выбора файла
    open_dialog->Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (open_dialog->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        pictureBox1->Image = gcnew Bitmap(open_dialog->FileName);
        container = new sf::Image(open_dialog->FileName);
    }
    return System::Void();
}


Что такое sf::Image? Это не родной тип C++/CLI или WinForms. Всегда указывайте используемые технологии/фреймворки/библиотеки.
